# Strange sound after replacing starter and battery

Tags: electrical, noise, kia, spectra

My 2007 Kia Spectra just had a starter and new battery put in. Upon starting the car squeals loud with the sound of bits of gravel moving thru something. This happens when the car in completely shut off and the key is out of the ignition. I was told it sounds like the ignition switch. Help, don't want the car to stop on me. Any help as to what it could be if not the ignition.

Comment: Can you post a detailed video of what's going on? Descriptions can sometimes get lost in translation.

Comment: Does the sound happen all of the time? Even when the engine is not running? My first thought is that the sound that you're describing could be a the starter continuing to run after the engine starts. But this would happen only when the car was running and would stop when you stopped the car. It would not happen when the car was completely shut off with key out of the ignition.

Comment: It would also help if you could tell us where the sound appears to be coming from and how loud it is. A continuous sound would suggest that it was related to the wiring between the starter and the battery. That sound would be relatively quiet, and you might smell some ozone. There might also be some smoke and your battery would probably run down very quickly.